# Прямая речь без кавычек?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, кавычки

Есть ли правила, допускающие введение прямой речи без кавычек?

- *Некоторые так и говорили: если бы мой супруг (супруга) меня уважал, то всё остальное можно было бы преодолеть. Или прямо противоположное — если бы он (она) заслуживал уважения, то я никогда бы не вёл себя подобным образом. Многие открыто заявляют: сначала заслужи уважение...*
  http://otrok-ua.ru/sections/art/show/ty_menja_uvazhaesh.html
- Может, эта прямая речь не совсем прямая речь: нет реального 1-го лица?
  В общем, как оформить корректно данные предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямая речь в кавычках пeредает сказанное **дословно**.  Слова "некоторые так и говорили" означают, что далее следует примерный пересказ, поэтому здесь нет прямой речи.  Приведенное Вами оформление корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы совершенно правы: нет реального 1-го лица. Предложения абсолютно правильны, оформление в кавычках было бы ошибкой.